# clickable 3D Object with description window in three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js

I have a 3d model of a car. Is it possible to have the user click on parts of the car and a infowindow or something similar will appear with a description of the parts? I haven't found any examples with clickable 3D Models where something like a popup window is triggered.
Is it even possible with three.js?

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes for how to do picking in three.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) this link. Using that example, in the javascript code, alter the code that changes material color and write a code to pop up a div. Thats it.